# Apache Flink connect versus join

Tags: join, stream, apache-flink, distributed-system

In Apache Flink stream processing  how is the join operation different than connect, and consequently how CoProcessFunction and ProcessJoinFunction differ, is that the onTimer function provided by CoProcessFunction? Can you please provide an example use case suitable for join / connect in a mutual exclusive way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is quite significant. In the case of Join, it works more or less like SQL Inner Join, so You need to provide fields that will be used for joining, also `Join` is evaluated over the window.

So, basically You define the key for each window that will be used to join and the window that will be used to evaluate results. The `ProcessJoinFunction` allows You processing the joined elements after they are processed **but You don't have control over the join mechanism itself i.e. the pair of already joined elements will be passed to the `ProcessJoinFunction`**

In case of `connect` You also can define keys (You don't have to though), but those will be used not for the join but to control flow through parallel instances of operators and for keyed state. So, in case of connect, there is no logic responsible for how the elements will be connected, but rather for each element from stream1 method `processElement1` will be called and for each element from stream2 method `processElement2` will be called. So, if You want to perform some kind of join You will have to implement the logic Yourself.

Comment: Thank you much clearer. so if I am connecting two streams S1 and S2 where S1 emits at time t1 (say event time) and then S2 emits at time t2, then t3 then t4, so I can conclude that as result of connecting the two streams  processElement1  will be called once at time ~time t1 and processElement2  will be called three times at ~ t2, t3 and  t4,... is that accurate?

Comment: Exactly :) Generally, if You want to have more sophisticated logic that joins those elements then `connect` is the preferred way I'd say.